# How should I do to make an elasticSearch , search query from Node.js correctly?

Tags: node.js, api, express, elasticsearch

I am stuck in a problem and can not figure out the solution.
I want to use an elasticSearch query from my nodejs. 
The problem is, I can make it work from postman, but not from node.

```
http://user:psd@my_domain:9200/ra_autocomplete/search
```

And from my nodejs app :

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'my_domain',
  port : 9200,
  protocol : 'http',
  auth : 'user:psd',
  maxRetries : 2
});
```

And then,

```
    client.search({
       index: "ra_autocomplete",
       body: {
         query: {
           m_prefix : {
           r_n : {
            query : my_var
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } , function(err, res) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(res);
  });
```

I get this error :

> Error: Not Found
>       at respond (my_path\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:307:15)
>       at checkRespForFailure 
>       (my_path\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:266:7)
>       at HttpConnector. 
>       (my_path\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\connectors\http.js:159:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.bound 
>       (my_path\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:729:21)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>     status: 404,
>     displayName: 'NotFound',
>     message: 'Not Found',
>     path: '/roads_autocomplete/_search',
>     query: {},
>     body: '{"query":{"m_prefix":{"r_n":{"query":"montexte a analyser"}}}}',
>     statusCode: 404,
>     response: '\r\n404 Not Found\r\n\r\n
>
> ## 404 Not Found
>
> \r\n
>
> ---
>
> nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)\r\n\r\n\r\n',
>     toString: [Function],
>     toJSON: [Function] }

Any help would be appreciated, the problem is, when I try to make it with postman, it goes well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not connecting to elastic search node.

Add your port and domain to into one line and then start by running a simple query.

```js
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
   host: 'localhost:9200',
   log: 'trace'
});

client.search({
    index: 'products',
    type: 'product',
    body: {
        query: {
            bool: {

            }
        }
    }
    }).then((body) => {
        return body;
    }, (error) => {
        console.trace(error.message);
    });
```

Comment: Infact, it was that: I had to make **host: 'my_domain:9200'** and 
 **httpAuth : 'user:psd'** so that it works. thank you.